# ORA-22288: passing xml file to SQL Developper

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, oracle-sqldeveloper

Do you have an idea how to solve this error? The file exists on my computer, but something is going wrong. I have created a XML file, later I have created a schema for it (`.xsd`) and now I want to connect the schema file with my oracle data base and after this function I would create a table for this schema.

I have also tried to place file in oracle directory, but it doesn't help.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/documentation/peldesana.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename('MAPE','peldesana.xsd'),
    LOCAL     => TRUE,
    GENTYPES  => FALSE, 
    GENTABLES => FALSE, 
    CSID      => nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
END;
```

Error:

> ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 822
> ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA", line 131
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> 22285. 00000 -  "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
>
> *Cause:    Attempted to access a directory that does not exist, or attempted to access a file in a directory that does not exist.
> *Action:   Ensure that a system object corresponding to the specified directory exists in the database dictionary, or make sure the name is correct.

Comment: I have created a directory
 'CREATE DIRECTORY 'MAPE AS 'C:\3_XML;' but it still doesnt help, despite there is a file 'peldesana.xsd'

Comment: "The file exists on my computer" - is the database also running on your computer, or do you access it remotely?

Comment: The database is running on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have generated.xsd file once more (using the same .xml file). And then I added one more line (OPTIONS => 2), everything works now.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/documentation/peldesana2.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename('INPUT_DIR','peldesana2.xsd'),
    LOCAL     => TRUE,
    GENTYPES  => FALSE, 
    GENTABLES => FALSE, 
    CSID      => nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'),
    OPTIONS    => 2);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a directory isn't enough.

A directory, object which points to a file system directory (folder), is created by `SYS`.

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create or replace directory xml_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.
```

Then you have to **grant privileges** on that directory to user which will be using it. If you'll only read data from it, grant `read`; if you'll also create files there, grant `write` as well:

```
SQL> grant read, write on directory xml_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Now, user `scott` will be able to access directory and files within.

Comment: I am managing database from the sys account, so there should not be problems of access rights.

Comment: But I cannot access the file for some reason, I checked it is in the correct location and I still get error 
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The system cannot find the file specified.